# What is the cause of this green and yellow ffmpeg artifact?

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libx264

I'm trying to convert a series of image frames into a video with `ffmpeg`. For some of the image series, I am getting a strange yellow/green artifact and I'm not sure what setting in the conversion is causing the artifact or the best way to fix it.

The command I'm using for the conversion is

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i inputs.txt -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 10 -vf "scale=1024:-2" -movflags +faststart video.mp4
```

A reproducible example with three image files and an associated `inputs.txt` file indicating the files and associated durations can be downloaded [here (Dropbox link)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3golifkg8ntxrm/ffmpeg_issue.zip?dl=0)

Here's the resulting artifact

[image]

And the GIF of the output

[image]

What settings could be causing this artifact, and what can I do to try to reduce/remove the artifact from the video? This happens on both versions of `ffmpeg` that I have tried:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma

ffmpeg version 3.1-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --as=yasm --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-version3 --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=qtkit --disable-indev=x11grab_xcb
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first input is grayscale 1-bit so I think that's throwing off the swscale chroma interpolation routine. Convert to RGBA before scaling.

```
-vf "format=rgba,scale=1024:-2"
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried that out on the example images that I posted and it does seem to work well. Let me check on a few more videos that I'm having issues with and will accept the answer once I'm able to confirm this in a few more cases. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not totally sure about the cause, so do you mind if I open a bug report with your inputs?

Comment: Sure that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind posting a link to the bug report when you file it?

Comment: Sorry, will get to this.

Comment: Got the same problem on [this image][1], but the artifacts are still there even with the format conversion.


  [1]: https://blog.benjojo.co.uk/asset/OHMMBrt565